# Can't get touch input from eGalax device to QtQuick application

Tags: qt, raspbian, qtquick2, evdev, eglfs

I'm trying to get **touch input** from a [eGalax resistive touch device](https://www.pollin.de/p/7-17-78-cm-display-set-mit-touchscreen-ls-7t-hdmi-dvi-vga-cvbs-120964?&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI3py22M7Z1wIVS40bCh0cdQJXEAQYASABEgLf6fD_BwE) to a **eglfs** window running the sample **QtQuick2** code. I'm failing for several days. The touchscreen is connected via USB to a Raspberry Pi B and works fine for the raspbian jessie desktop. But if I run the sample QtQuick2 code the application don't get any touch input. However using a mouse works fine for the sample code.

I've already try to use tsLib but ts_test shows always 0 for x and y coordinates.
I also try to use "./samplecode -plugin evdevtouch:/dev/input/event1" without success. If the screen in touched the output "Unhandled MSC event code MSC_SCAN (0x4)" is printed. So, the application or the mouse cursor is not responsive.

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment. qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys: ("eglfs_brcm", "eglfs_kms") 
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys (sorted): ("eglfs_brcm", "eglfs_kms") 
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Trying to load device EGL integration "eglfs_brcm" qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Using EGL device integration "eglfs_brcm" 
Unable to query physical screen size, defaulting to 100 dpi. 
To override, set QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT (in millimeters). 
qt.qpa.input: libinput: input device 'eGalax Inc. Touch', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Mouse 
qt.qpa.input: libinput: input device 'eGalax Inc. Touch', /dev/input/event0 is a pointer caps 
qt.qpa.input: libinput: input device 'eGalax Inc. Touch', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Tablet 
qt.qpa.input: libinput: eGalax Inc. Touch: tablet unknown to libwacom qt.qpa.input: libinput: input device 'eGalax Inc. Touch', /dev/input/event1 is a tablet 
qt.qpa.input: Using xkbcommon for key mapping 
qt.qpa.input: evdevtouch: Adding device at "/dev/input/event1" 
qt.qpa.input: evdevtouch: Using device /dev/input/event1 
qt.qpa.input: evdevtouch: /dev/input/event1: Protocol type B (mtdev) (multi) qt.qpa.input: evdevtouch: /dev/input/event1: min X: 0 max X: 0 
qt.qpa.input: evdevtouch: /dev/input/event1: min Y: 0 max Y: 0 
qt.qpa.input: evdevtouch: /dev/input/event1: min pressure: 0 max pressure: 0 qt.qpa.input: evdevtouch: /dev/input/event1: device name: eGalax Inc. Touch JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.
qt.qpa.input: evdevtouch: Updating QInputDeviceManager device count: 1  touch devices, 0 pending handler(s) 
qt.qpa.input: libinput: Unhandled MSC event code MSC_SCAN (0x4) 
qt.qpa.input: libinput: Unhandled MSC event code MSC_SCAN (0x4) 
qt.qpa.input: libinput: Unhandled MSC event code MSC_SCAN (0x4) 
qt.qpa.input: libinput: Unhandled MSC event code MSC_SCAN (0x4)
```

Same for using ./samplecode -plugin evdevmouse:/dev/input/event1" but here its possible to move the mouse cursor.

Some helpful information
dmesg:

```
usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=0001 
usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 
usb 1-1.3: Product: Touch 
usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: eGalax Inc. 
systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-ttyAMA0.device... 
systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch. systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch. 
input: eGalax Inc. Touch as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0001/input/input0 
input: eGalax Inc. Touch as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0001/input/input1 
hid-generic 0003:0EEF:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.12 Pointer [eGalax Inc. Touch] on usb-20980000.usb-1.3/input0
```

running evtest (seems to be fine in my opinion):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ evtest /dev/input/event1
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xeef product 0x1 version 0x112
Input device name: "eGalax Inc. Touch"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 320 (BTN_TOOL_PEN)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value    315
      Min        0
      Max     2047
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value    689
      Min        0
      Max     2047
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1511610558.640532, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0042
Event: time 1511610558.640532, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1511610558.640532, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1362
Event: time 1511610558.640532, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 978
Event: time 1511610558.640532, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1511610558.672506, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0042
Event: time 1511610558.672506, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1511610558.672506, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
```

Maybe anyone has a clue for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in tslib specific to exactly your touchscreen device, when used with relatively new kernels. If you use the very latest version 1.15-rc2, soon to be 1.15, and `module_raw input` in your ts.conf, things should work just fine for you.